# MegaCli64 -PDInfo shows drive but other commands says device does not exist

Tags: megacli

A drive recently went missing on our IBM server. It has happened on other servers in the past and I usually just replace them with out a problem. On one it is not automatically adding the new drive.

I run the command:

```
MegaCli64 -PDInfo -PhysDrv [252:0] -a0
```

and I receive the drive information:

```
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 0
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 11
WWN: 5000C50055138398
Sequence Number: 17
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 0 KB [0x0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 0 KB [0x0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 0 KB [0x0 Sectors]
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: B559
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c50055138399
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 1(path0)
Inquiry Data: IBM-ESXSST9300605SS     B5596XP3S49F0215B559
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None
Device Speed: Unknown
Link Speed: Unknown
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: Unknown
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: Unknown
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No
```

If I try to add the drive as a replacement/hot spare/ or any form of manipulation I receive the error.

```
sudo MegaCli64 -PdReplaceMissing -PhysDrv [?:0] -Array0 -Row1 -a0

Adapter: 0: Failed to replace Missing PD at Array 0, Row 1.

FW error description:
 The requested command cannot be completed, as the specified device does not exist.

Exit Code: 0x0c
```

How do I replace the missing disk in the raid?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I replace the missing disk in the raid?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error today.
On solution for me was to dump the events on the RAID Card:

```
megacli -AdpEventLog -GetEvents -f events -aAll
```

After reading the events, I found my problem:

```
Event Description: Inserted: PD 07(e0x20/s7)
Event Description: PD 07(e0x20/s7) is not a certified drive
```

My RAID Card, on my DELL server, is a H700 RAID Card. It only support specific DELL Disks.

I have read that a Firmware upgrade can remove this limitation, I will try. I hope you will have a better solution in your case...