# LSI RAID confusion

Tags: lsi, megaraid, megacli

I've got a Cisco UCS server with a LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2008 [Falcon] (rev 03). This has 2 disks configured as RAID1. controller. One of the disks was reporting a very high failure count. I'm not very fdamiliar with LSI cards so I thought the safest solution was to shut the box down, remove the drive, check the serial number and then insert the new drive after booting up. This was probably the wrong way to do things. I now can't convince the LSI controller to add the new drive back into the array.

`MegaCli64 -PDInfo -PhysDrv \[64:0\] -a0` reports the new drive:

```
Enclosure Device ID: 64
Slot Number: 0
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 4
WWN: 5000C50098CDE094
Sequence Number: 1
...
Raw Size: 273.539 GB [0x22314357 Sectors]
...
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
...
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No
```

I only have a single RAID set - Array 0:

```
root@example:/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli# ./MegaCli64 -CfgDsply -a0 | grep Reference
Span Reference: 0x00
```

But I can't seem to add this into the array:

```
root@example:/usr/local/sbin# MegaCli64 -PDHSP -Set -PhysDrv\[64:0\] -a0
                                     
Adapter: 0: Set Physical Drive at EnclId-64 SlotId-0 as Hot Spare Failed.

FW error description: 
 The requested command cannot be completed, as the specified device does not exist.  

Exit Code: 0x0c
```

and

```
root@example:/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli# MegaCli64 -PdReplaceMissing -PhysDrv\[64:0\] -array0 -row0 -a0
                                     
Adapter: 0: Failed to replace Missing PD at Array 0, Row 0.

FW error description: 
 The requested command cannot be completed, as the specified device does not exist.  

Exit Code: 0x0c
```

Comment: It can be a problem regarding certified drives. Can you follow the steps described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/568941/megacli64-pdinfo-shows-drive-but-other-commands-says-device-does-not-exist) ?

Comment: `Event Description: PD 04(e0xff/s0) is not supported` :(